# The footer to our website has disappeared on desktop version, not mobile, but relevant HTML/CSS hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My small library has a website that was created in HTML and CSS by a previous employee. I know the the display of the site is dynamic based on screen size-- the mobile site is slightly different from the desktop site. It appears he used some libraries from JQuery, too. I have a very limited background in coding, so I make only minor content changes and NO functional changes. At some point, while I was on vacation, the footer of our website stopped displaying in the desktop version of the site, but it still shows in the mobile site.

I have audited the HTML and CSS files against the archived files to be sure I didn't inadvertently make any changes before I left. I have checked the versions of files that are rarely used and noticed they haven't been changed since 2017. I commented out the CSS and ran just the HTML locally to see if there was a stylesheet difference I was missing (though I haven't edited them), but I couldn't get anything to display in the footer. The footer has a widget that displays one iframe with a link to another website, a second iframe with a link to a calendar, and a group of icons with links to our partners. Again, everything worked fine until a month ago on the mobile and desktop sites, and I can view the footer if I resize my desktop browser to something very narrow.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-109165971-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-109165971-1');
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="63DD6F645CCF71531665417F6978B20A" />
    <title>Welcome to the Toccoa-Stephens County Public Library</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome the Toccoa Stephens County Library! Celebrating 80 years of operation and still going strong!" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Toccoa-Stephens County Public Library, Northeast Georgia Public Libraries, search catalog, account, events, hours, new books, Toccoa, library, Friends of the Library, Stephens County, opac, steam, 3d printing, makerspace, state park pass" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="author" content="Literati Ltd" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!--header-->
  <header>
   <!--insert a lot of contents organized into tabs-->

<!--End Navigation tabs,begin accordion. tabs.css media queries will cause tabs to display:none at 500px and accordion to display. 
Any information added to tabs must be duplicated in the accordion-->


  <div class="container">


    <!--Home-->
   <!--insert a lot of contents organized into accordion tabs-->    



<footer>

    <div class="widgets">

    <div class="new-books">
      <iframe id="newbooks" src="https://gapines.org/opac/extras/browse/html-full/item-age/NEG-TOCCOA/1/5"></iframe>
        </div>
    <div id="tscpl-calendar">
      <iframe id="calendar" src="https://teamup.com/ksx6i3x71k3mbbkzbk?view=a&disableSidepanel=1&showLogo=0&showHeader=0&showTitle=0&showViewSelector=0"></iframe>
        <div id="bottom-right"><a href="calendar.html"><strong>SEE ALL EVENTS</strong></a>  </div>
    </div>  
      </div>

</div>


<div id="social">
  <h3>More to See!</h3>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/toccoastephenscountypubliclibrary/" target="_blank"><img class="socialpics" src="images/facebook.png" title="LIKE US ON FACEBOOK!" alt="LIKE US ON FACEBOOK!" /></a>
  <a href="https://my.nicheacademy.com/api/widgetCarousel/toccoa-stephenslibrary/load" target="_blank"><img class="socialpics" src="images/niche.png" title="TUTORIALS FOR OUR DIGITAL SERVICES" alt="TUTORIALS FOR OUR DIGITAL SERVICES" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.galileo.usg.edu/express?link=ztbo" target="_blank"><img class="socialpics" src="images/tumblebook.png" title="MORE EBOOKS FOR KIDS!" alt="MORE EBOOKS FOR KIDS!" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.galileo.usg.edu/express?link=zkpl" target="_blank"><img class="socialpics" src="images/novelist.png" title="FIND A GOOD RECOMMENDATION WITH NOVELIST" alt="FIND A GOOD RECOMMENDATION WITH NOVELIST" /></a>
    </div>  


</footer>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<br></br>
<p align="right">E-Verify ID#792629</p>


<!--Javascript used-->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tabs.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/gcal.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/agenda.js"></script>
<script src="https://my.nicheacademy.com/api/widget/toccoa-stephenslibrary"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the primary CSS code that relates to that section:

```
#social {
  width: 375px;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.socialpics {


display: inline-flex;
  margin: 15px 30px 0px 30px;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

#newbooks {
  float:left;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  margin: 1%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#tscpl-calendar {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: .5%;
    display: inline-flex;
    float: left;
    width: 415px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}

#calendar {
  width: 415px;
  height: 225px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  overflow: auto;
}

#bottom-right {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

#tscpl-calendar a:link {
    background-color: #379676;
    color: white;
}

#tscpl-calendar a:visited {
    background-color: #379676;
    color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {
  .gapines {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
  .gapines {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.new-books {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  overflow: scroll !important;
  padding-bottom: 125%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.new-books iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
}

#tscpl-calendar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#calendar {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

#social {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
}

.after-box {
    clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width : 1279px) {
  #tscpl-calendar{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    max-width: 35%;
    min-width: 25%;
  }

  #calendar {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    max-width: 99%;
    min-width: 40%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  .new-books{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
    display: block;
    max-width: 50%;
    min-width: 35%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }

  .new-books iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;
  }

  #social {
    max-width: 45%;
    max-width: 25%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .socialpics {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 2%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width : 799px) {
 #tscpl-calendar {  
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 95%;
  }

 #calendar {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 95%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }
  .new-books{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30.50%;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 90%;
    max-height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  }

  .new-books iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: block;
  }

  #social {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 90%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  .socialpics {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

There is another CSS file, but I don't think it's quite relevant. However, I'm definitely a newbie, so if something's missing, please let me know. Also, there may be something related to JavaScript that I need to include. Let me know if I'm missing that.

I expect my page to display the footer, regardless of the device accessing it. I also need specific instructions for fixing any coding errors, even if you have to point me to a "for Dummies" resource. We have no real programmers here, but we have plenty of books.

On review by a commenter, the other CSS file **is** important, so here is a scaled down version:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.tabs {
  margin-top: .5%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 98%;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 485px;
    margin-bottom: .5%;
}

.tabs nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background: #379676;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 150px;
  height: inherit;
}

.tabs nav a {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.tabs .content {
  padding: 15px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 150px;
  color: #2b2626;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear 0s;
}


.tabs .content.visible {
  padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  opacity: .87;
}

.tabs .content p { padding-bottom: 1px; }

.tabs .content p:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 0px; }

/* Beginning of Accordion nav */

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -999;
}

.accordion label {
  display:block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #379676;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.accordion-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .40s;
}

.accordion-content {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .87;;
  margin: 1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion input:checked ~ .accordion-content {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .tabs {display: none;
  height: 0px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) {
  .container {display: inline-flex;
  height: 0px;}
}
```

Basically, if you're on a mobile site, the tabs on the side are all collapsed until you touch one of them, but the footer displays at all times.

Comment: Well if https://www.toccoastephenslibrary.org/ is the site it looks like the `<footer>` is inside a `.container` that is set to `display: none` on everything 501px and higher (desktop). The code you provided doesn't display this behavior because the css that causes this is the `tabs.css` file

Comment: @zgood-- Yes, that is the correct site. Are you referring to this line in tabs.css? 
       
`@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) { .container {display: none;  height: 0px;} }`

I see that, too, but the footer displays correctly in the archive and was displaying correctly up until a few weeks ago. I'm not sure what the value should be to display the footer and not change the appearance of the tabs on the side.  
I'll add this tabs.css code to my original post for easier viewing. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** After looking at the website, I have a solution:

As another user has also pointed out, your  is within a  , there is a media query which sets this to 'display: none;'. This means anything within this will be hidden on those media specific screen sizes.

A solution is to take the

```
<footer> ... </footer>.
```

and place this just before the closing body tag like this...

```
        <footer>
            <div class="widgets">
                <div class="new-books">
                    <iframe id="newbooks" src="Welcome%20to%20the%20Toccoa-Stephens%20County%20Public%20Library_files/5.html"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div id="tscpl-calendar">
                    <iframe id="calendar" src="Welcome%20to%20the%20Toccoa-Stephens%20County%20Public%20Library_files/ksx6i3x71k3mbbkzbk.html" class="fc fc-unthemed fc-ltr">
                        <div class="fc-toolbar fc-header-toolbar">
                            <div class="fc-left">
                                <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fc-right">
                                <button type="button" class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">today</button>
                                <div class="fc-button-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="fc-prev-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left">
                                        <span class="fc-icon fc-icon-left-single-arrow"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="fc-next-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right">
                                        <span class="fc-icon fc-icon-right-single-arrow"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fc-center">

                            </div>
                            <div class="fc-clear">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fc-view-container">
                            <div class="fc-view fc-listMonth-view fc-list-view fc-widget-content">
                                <div class="fc-scroller" style="overflow: hidden auto;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </iframe>
                    <div id="bottom-right">
                        <a href="https://www.toccoastephenslibrary.org/calendar.html"><strong>SEE ALL EVENTS</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

This will take the footer out of the container which is being hidden on desktop.

Comment: Connor, I see what you mean, but I'm a little confused. The media queries do have 0;, but the .new-books still displays just fine on a smaller screen, and the class has a height specified at 250px before the media queries. Also, the iframes don't display *at all*,even though they have properties listed. I'm not sure why 0; height in the media queries for .new-books would keep everything else in the footer from displaying. I did apply the change and tested, but the footer still doesn't appear on a standard screen. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Holly, Css works with the latest code being the highest priority. Can you attach a link to the site and I can take a look? :) , It seems like the media queries are changing the settings for specific devices but it's hard to see without having the code open infront of me :)

Best, 
Connor

Comment: The site is <https://www.toccoastephenslibrary.org>. The relevant code may be in the tabs.css file, which zgood mentions above. I'll append my original post with that code so you and others can view it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Connor Brown! There are a couple of words missing from your answer, but I think I follow you. The intended behavior of the "display:none" was for the tabs to not display when a user is viewing from a mobile device and for the accordion to not display when the user is viewing from the desktop. Somehow, the footer is being included in the container that is defining the accordion. I have applied the updates you suggested above, made sure the division tags are all closed, what am I missing? The javascript comes before the closing body and html tags, right?

Comment: No Problem Holly, that's right. So the footer should come before the closing body tags which should then be followed by the javascript. Then it should just be the closing body tag and closing html tag left